# How to create a file with complete data in Gstreamer's filesink?

Tags: opencv, gstreamer

I am currently using Gstreamer to capture output from a local file and save the stream as a file. I have successfully implemented the functionality to capture the output, but I'm facing an issue with the filesink element. Instead of creating the file once with all the data, it creates the file incrementally, resulting in a growing file size over time until the pipeline completes the execution.

Here's the pipeline I'm using:

`gst-launch-1.0 <source> ! <other elements> ! filesink location=output_file`

Is there a way to ensure that the file is created only once, with all the data present at that point? I would like to avoid having the file size increase incrementally as the stream progresses.

Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!